# How to download a .docx file in AngularJs controller from Node.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, download, docx

I've been looking in stackoverflow for some answer but I didn't succeed.

I have a node.js method in routes which generates a .docx template from another template with docxtemplater library.

I send a post from angularjs to my /api/generateReport with some data and I generate this .docx but I cant manage to send it. 
It is not recommendable nor secure placing the file in /public dir but I can't download it if I place the file in /public dir and I provide the file path to AngularJs.

I've read about blob and other stuff but I can't manage to download a .docx file.

PS: I'm using $resource directive to handle api requests and I have set responseType to `arrayBuffer`

```js
angular.module('MyApp')
  .factory('GenerateReport', function($http, $location,$resource, $rootScope, $alert, $window) {

       return $resource("/api/GenerateReport/:id",{}, {
            'query': {
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: false
            },
            responseType: 'arrayBuffer'
        });

  });
```

I send the response this way.

```
 var fileDocx = fs.readFileSync(__base + "/plantillaSalida.docx", "binary");
 res.send(fileDocx);
```

Response is received in angular controller:

```js
GenerateReport.save({
  projectExecution: $scope.projectExecution,
  auditingProject: $scope.auditingProject,
  participants: $scope.participants,
  exampleProjects: $scope.exampleProjects
  
  }, function(response) {

/***What to to here??***/

    $mdToast.show(
    $mdToast.simple()
    .content('Informe generado')
    .position('bottom right left')
    .hideDelay(3000)
    );
  },
  function(error) {
    console.log("error");
    $mdToast.show(
    $mdToast.simple()
    .content('Error al general el informe')
    .position('bottom right left')
    .hideDelay(3000)
    );
  }
);
```

Comment: Have you looked at possibly sending as a document buffer?  Browserify supports browser side buffers so it's the same kind of buffer that is on the nodejs side of things but you can send it in the buffer then translate it back into the document from the browser side

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to add download header to your file and link it using hyperlink (`<a href="/download">`)

```
var path = require('path');
var mime = require('mime');

app.get('/download', function(req, res){

  var file = __base + "/plantillaSalida.docx";

  var filename = path.basename(file);
  var mimetype = mime.lookup(file);

  res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + filename);
  res.setHeader('Content-type', mimetype);

  var filestream = fs.createReadStream(file);
  filestream.pipe(res);
});
```

If you are using express use below code

```
app.get('/download', function(req, res){
    var file = __base + "/plantillaSalida.docx";
    var filename = path.basename(file);
    res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + filename);
    res.download(file); 
 });
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the response. But I need to handle the request via angularjs controller because i need to post some data so I can't use href directly.

Comment: @JoséGómezCheca  add link to <a> and you can trigger click event of <a> on success callback. Just an idea.